# Tracking progress of while loop and display results after complete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, while-loop, progress-bar

I have a `while` loop that I'm using to cycle through items in my database and I'm trying to keep track of the progress.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query)) { stuff }
```

Now for each item the while() pulls from the database I check an external site for data, so each item takes about a half second to load. So for example it cycles through 88 items and takes roughly 35-40 seconds to completely finish. I was wondering if there was a way for me to load this data in the background while showing progress text saying "X out of 88 items checked" and then finally displaying everything?

I'm just learning PHP and understand that I'll mostly likely have to use AJAX or jQuery, so any help getting pointed in the right direction would be great!

Comment: [You want to look into this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

Comment: Alright, I'll have a look at that post.